# TextBox.Text not updating if populated on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox that shows a custom/human filename (FDNameBox) that is populated on page load with the custom name of a file i.e. "Invoice for John" when the filename is "invoice1234.doc"

```
FDNameBox.Text = strHumanName;
```

All works fine, nice and easy.

What I've been trying to do all morning is to get the database entry to update with anything other than "Invoice for John". Whatever is typed into the Textbox just seems to be ignored and it uses whatever is on page load.

If I don't auto-populate the field and have the Textbox blank on page load it all works fine but that is not what I want to do.

```
string strNewHumanName = FDNameBox.Text;
```

The above just doesn't seem to get anything new (called from a button click event)

How do I get it to update when something in the field changes? I've tried various types of:

```
protected void FDNameBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

...but I'm just not doing something correctly. Feels like something should be really easy but I'm just going around in circles now with my code and on google.

AutoPostBack just reloads the page and auto-populates the field as before

Answer (score 0):

The issue to keep in mind?

For every web page I created (at least the last 100+ of them), is that page load fires each and every time.

So, even if you drop into the page a simple asp.net button? When you click on that button, both the page load event triggers, and THEN your button code.

Since page load re-fires over and over durng "genreal" page operation, then setup code placed in that code stub also runs EVERY time.

So, what we "really" require here is a real first page load, or a real first bit of code to run ONLY the first time.

as a result, code to setup a text box, load up a grid, combo boxes (drop downlist) etc.?

it has to be placed in the REAL first page load.

You thus in the page load code stub will write this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";

            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GHotels.DataSource = rstData;
                GHotels.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, note how we added a if (!IsPostBack) stub. Quite much every web page you create will have such a !IsPostBack stub. This is your "setup" code and loading of controls code.

If you don't check !IsPostBack, then your code to re-load the text box will run over and over - including overwriting anything the user enters into that text box.

so, in above, we have a gridview like this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" CssClass="table"
             AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"       />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"               />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Dexcripton"  />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Row Click">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdRowClickl" runat="server" Text="View" 
                            CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdRowClickl_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

So, when we run, we get this:

[image]

Note that even in the grid view row, I have a plain jane button, and when we click that button, I ceratinly don't want to re-load the grid view each time, so I placed such setup code inside of the !IsPostBack code stub on page load. And as a result, only on the first "real" page load do I run such code to load up the grid, or combo box, or text boxe(s) or whatever.

Comment: Perfectly explained and I learnt a lot thank you for taking the time. I'll give it a go. I didn't realise that when interacting with buttons etc it loaded the whole page again.

Comment: I came from desktop land - vb, access, foxpro etc. All of those have a load event and it fires only on first page load. Web is different, and this little issue is often left out of tutorials etc.